# javafx bind button disable property to folder exists

Tags: javafx

I have a stage with a button "Continue" which is want to be disabled until a folder "folderFramework" is created.

Here is my snippet which unfortunately does not work.

```
File folderFramework = new File("path to the folder");
    ObjectProperty<File> file = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
    file.set(folderFramework); // tested with setValue too...

    BooleanBinding fileExists = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() ->
                    file.get() != null && file.get().exists(),
            file);

    btnContinue.disableProperty().bind(fileExists.not());
```

What am I missing? Thank you!

Comment: Your binding won't be updated when the file is created (or deleted), i.e. when the result of calling `file.get().exists()` changes. It will only be updated when the value of `file` changes, i.e. when `file.set()` or `file.setValue()` are called with an actual different `File` instance. The result of `File.exists()` simply isn't observable in the JavaFX sense; to do what I think you're trying to do here, you'd need to implement a [`WatchService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/WatchService.html), and update a JavaFX property from it.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WatchService in the Task did the trick for me. Here is the final solution:

```
private void handleBtnContinue() {

    // task definition for watching changes in framework folder
    Task<Void> watchingTask = new Task<>() {

        @Override
        protected Void call() {

            WatchService watchService;
            try {
                watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();


                Path path = Paths.get(ConstantUtils.getPathFolderFramework());

                path.register(
                        watchService,
                        StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE,
                        StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE,
                        StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);

                WatchKey key;
                boolean quitTask = false;
                while ((key = watchService.take()) != null && !quitTask) {
                    for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {

                        // when src folder is cloned -> enable the button continue
                        if (event.kind().toString().equals("ENTRY_MODIFY") && event.context().toString().equals("src")) {

                            // enable btn continue
                            Platform.runLater(() -> btnContinue.setDisable(false));

                            // end the task
                            quitTask = true;
                        }

                    }
                    key.reset();
                }
            } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                LOG.error("Error occurred while trying to watch changes in folder: " + ConstantUtils.getPathFolderAppData());
            }
            return null;
        }
    };

    // run the task in a new thread
    Thread th = new Thread(watchingTask);
    th.setDaemon(true);
    th.start();
}
```